# Envelope of holomorphy for the union of two balls

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Checking my file archive I found an unpublished note by Bros and Glaser in which they calculated the envelope of holomorphy of the union of two overlapping polydiscs $P_j\subset\mathbb C^n$, $j=1,2$. Does somebody know a similar result in case when the $P_j$ are overlapping balls?